# When Entity Framework auto generated property gets populated

Tags: entity-framework

Consider I have the following classes:

```
class User
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id {get; set;}

   public string UserName {get; set;}
}

class MyUsersContext: DbContext
{
   DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
}

class MyRepository
{
   MyUsersContext _db; //INJECTED

   User AddUser(string userName)
   {
      var newBorn = new User() { UserName = userName };

      _db.Users.Add(newBorn);

      return newBorn;
   }

}

class MyMemProvider: MembershipProvider
{
   MyRepository repo; //INJECTED

   public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username...
   {
      var ret = repo.AddUser(username);
      return new MembershipUser(System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider.Name, ret.UserName...
   }

}
```

This is a stripped down version of my custom membership provider for ASP.NET MVC3 site. At what point User.Id gets filled with actual Guid in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply **DatabaseGeneratedOption** on your Id attribute.

```
class User
{
   [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public Guid Id {get; set;}

   public string UserName {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this should not be an obligatory step. It is obvious that a developer would like not to be bothered with Key generation.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov Funny you say that. I'm here for the opposite. Need a property to be a key but have to disable database generation so I can populate manually.